# How can I export elevation layer data and OpenStreetMap layer data as shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, openstreetmap, srtm

I am a newbie in QGIS looking to obtain elevation data with respect to a map. As I could not find any free elevation data, therefore I adopted the following approach.

1. Elevation data: I got the elevation data by selecting an area of interest on the ESRI satellite map and used the SRTM Downloader to extract the elevation data. The elevation data file was downloaded as .hgt format. I opened this file using qgis to see the elevation of the area of interest.
2. OpenStreetMap: I mounted the OpenStreetMap on top of the elevation data.

Now I can see the elevation on the map along with street names.

My aim is to be able to export this data to another software which takes shapefiles. How can I package the elevation data and OpenStreetMap as shape file and export it? One thing I did not understand is that I was not able to see the attributes table for elevation data file. Is my method correct? Is there a better way or source to achieve the above? I am not from the GIS field at all, but I need the data.

I am running QGIS 3.10 on an Ubunut18 machine.

Edit version:
After the direction of GBG, I achieved the following:(How to save this as a shapefile?)

[image]

Comment: Shapefile will only store points, lines, or polygons.  Best to generate contour lines from the SRTM as a shapefile. Are you viewing the OpenStreetMap data as a web mapping service?  If so, you can download the actual data and then use QGIS to save it to a shapefile.  See here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data.  Attribute table for the elevation data? - that is because these data are floating point data.  You would only see a table if these data were interval data.

Comment: @GBG Thank you for your kind support. I now managed to import a DEM file for my area from opendem.info. i then created contour lines from it. I am simply using the openstreetmap from exz tiles. Now i have the map at the bottom, dem file with contour lines. how can i clip these two and create a single shapefile? or do i have to create separate shapefiles ?Also, i am not able to save as shapefile for both layers. I have put a picture of the work done so far in the edit section of my question. Please pardon me for being silly here.

Comment: OSM is served as image tiles, not vector data.  You can't export image tiles as a shapefile.  You will have to download or extract the OSM vector data from overpass turbo, geofabrik.de, or some other service.  You can then use the clip tool to clip vector data.  You technically could combine the contour lines and streets into one shapefile since they are both lines, but it would make more sense to have one shapefile for roads and one for contours.  Just my 2 cents.